# Remaining tax resident in the UK while spending less than half the year in the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, residency

I'm a UK citizen.

So far this tax year, I have been outside the UK for approx 3 months.

I now plan to be abroad again, and expect to stay outside the UK for the remainder of the tax year (until 5th April 2023).

In total, this is > half the year.

I have done [some research](https://www.bdo.co.uk/en-gb/insights/tax/private-client/leaving-the-uk) and it looks like I can still remain tax resident in the UK during this time. From the "Sufficient ties test" on the linked website, I have the following ties:

`2`. Accommodation tie (during my time in the UK this tax year I have been living with my parents)

`4`. 90 day tie ("the individual has been present in the UK for more than 90 days in either of the previous two tax years")

`5`. Country tie ("the individual is present in the UK at midnight in the tax year as much as (or more than) they are present in any other single country. This tie applies to ‘leavers’ only (see below)")

I expect to have spent approx 144 days in the UK this tax year, which the website says means I only require 1 tie to remain resident.

Could anyone please give me some advice on what steps I need to take? How do I prove the ties, what paperwork do I need to submit? Thank you.

Comment: Not sure about UK, I'm German. However, when I went to work in academia abroad for 3 consecutive 1-year contracts I asked the tax office what I need to do and they decided that I stay German tax resident, because my center of life stayed in Germany: they said it is expected for academics to gain work experience abroad (and likely eventually return). They asked questions whether I still had a residency in Germany (yes: I registered at my parents' address, so e.g. my car could stay German) stay member of sports/alpine club/church or the like. Also, are the stays connected to your work in the UK?

Comment: Please can you clarify why you would like to remain a tax resident of the UK, and whether the question is related to some dual tax-residency and double taxation arrangements? // [This guidance](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/get-a-certificate-of-residence) may be helpful in regards to paperwork.

Comment: Sounds about right but why do you care? Does anybody ever check? The way these rules work, especially in borderline cases, is typically that you want to *avoid* being a tax resident and the tax authorities don't want you to be able to do that while actually living in the country. OTOH, don't think that meeting some test or convincing HMRC that you are a resident automatically means you will not also be considered a resident in some other country. That's not how this works and would be a different question.